# How to sum values inside v-for statement (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Here is my code below

```
<td v-for="config in configs" v-if="config">
    <input type="number" v-model="config.score" v-on:keyup="computeTestScores(allocation, $event)">
 </td>
<td><span class="subtotal"></span></td>`
```

how do i compute the ***subtotal***? Secondly, if the values of any input changes, i want to be able ***update the total class***;

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to compute the sum with v-for. V-for is meant for presentation.

Instead add a computed value that calculates the subtotal. Inside the computed you should loop through the array, calculate the sum and return it. The computed property also calculates the new value automatically if any of the inputs change.

Comment: now the problem is that my v-for loop for configs is inside another v-for loop called allocations. can you do me a quick short code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may sum the values of your array with the `reduce` function. The total will update automatically if any score changes.

```
<td><span class="subtotal">{{ configs.reduce((a, c) => a + parseInt(c.score), 0) }}</span></td>
```